# What does the (S) mean in the stat blocks for NPCs in some of the books?

Tags: unknown-armies

I've been reading some of some of the supplemental books for UA such as The Statosphere, and I noticed that some of the NPC stat blocks have a (S) after one of the stats. For example, Ellison Blanke, Agent of Solace has it after her Speed stat. What does this signify?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It's how the first edition rulebook handled initiative for GMCs.**

From page 52 of *Unknown Armies, 1e*:

> GM characters (GMCs) determine initiative in a different way that doesn't involve dice. All GMCs in this rulebook have either an (F) or an (S) next to their speed scores. (F) means *failed* and (S) means *succeeded*. All GMCs' initiative results are always equal to their Speed scores—as if they had rolled the dice and scored exactly their speeds—but the (F) or (S) indicates whether they go in the successful-initiative part of the round or the failed-initiative part of the round. As a rule, major GMCs get an (S) and minor ones get an (F).